# onResize Event Duplicating Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm having trouble with the onResize event. I have an if/else statement that checks if the window is resized < 768. The code works great but on every resize, it duplicates my prepend on every resize event trigger. Is there a way to make it happen only exceeding or below the 767 window size?

```
<div class="author-wrap">
    <div class="the">Sample</div>
</div>
```

onResize:

```
onResize = function() {
    var responsive_viewport = $(window).width();
    if (responsive_viewport < 768) {
        $('.the').prepend('<h3>Hi</h3>');
    } else {
    }
}
$(document).ready(onResize);
$(window).bind('resize', onResize);
```

Here's the code on jsfiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/K7Ugc/1/

Comment: did you tested this code in standalone html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the prepended element already exists. I have in mind this tricky way

```
onResize = function() {
    var responsive_viewport = $(window).width();
    var author_page = $('.main-content.author-archive');
    var author_name = $('h3.cat-label strong').text();
    var author_wrap = $('.author-wrap');
    if (responsive_viewport < 768) {
      if (!$('.the h3').text()){
        $('.the').prepend('<h3>Hi</h3>');
      }
    } else {
    }
}
$(document).ready(onResize);
$(window).bind('resize', onResize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for it to only run once? You can unbind the event if that's what you're looking to do:

```
onResize = function() {
    var responsive_viewport = $(window).width();
    var author_page = $('.main-content.author-archive');
    var author_name = $('h3.cat-label strong').text();
    var author_wrap = $('.author-wrap');
    if (responsive_viewport < 768) {
        alert(responsive_viewport);
        $('.the').prepend('<h3>Hi</h3>');
        $(window).unbind();
    } else {
    }
}
```